# .Net core 6 Post request, postman returns 404 on IIS

Tags: .net, post, iis, httprequest

I have a Post request like this:

```
    [HttpPost("storesubmission")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> StoreSubmission([FromBody]TestModel tModel)
    {
            mt.name = tModel.name;
            mt.age = tModel.age;
            mt.submittedBy = tModel.submittedBy;
            mt.submittedAt = tModel.submittedAt;
            mt.province = tModel.province;
            mt.tractId = tModel.tractId;  
            mt.referenceNumber = tModel.referenceNumber;
            _context.TestModels.Add(mt);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(mt);
    }
```

When I test it on my local machine it works fine, but when I publish it on our IIS server the POST doesn't work. The strange thing is that I also have GET methods that work fine on local and Server, but none of my POST requests work.
I have an API key for the request and here is my Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProntoConnection"));
});


var corsPolicy = "_corsPolicy";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(corsPolicy,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy
                               .WithOrigins("https://example.com")
                               .AllowAnyMethod()
                              .AllowAnyHeader()
                              .AllowCredentials();
                      });
});


var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors(corsPolicy);
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Here is my request in Postman
[image]

There are no errors. It seems like it doesn't even reach the endpoint, so it only gives The specified URL cannot be found.

Comment: How are you configuring iis?

Comment: You will have to let FRT reveal what's the cause of 404, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing

Comment: @DanielA.White What do you mean by configuring? I have other web API's there and they are working fine. I have checked the settings and they are the same. I suspected may be I need to explicitly allow POST in HTTP verbs but that didn't help.

Comment: @LexLi There is no FRT under my sites in my IIS

Comment: @LexLi  Also as I mentioned it doesn't even hit the endpoint to create any logs.

Comment: FRT is an IIS feature/role service you must install separately. It's not surprising that such requests never hit your ASP.NET Core endpoint, and I am suggesting FRT because it can trace whether the same requests land on IIS pipeline. We will see.

Comment: @LexLi I noticed that this works when using FromForm and add it as form values, but not FromBody. Unfortunately in this case, I can only use FromBody. Any suggestions.

Comment: If that's the new finding, then likely you hit one of the request filtering rules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis Go to IIS log files and read the actual substatus code for such 404 errors. The substatus code matches the corresponding filtering rules and you can tune there.

Comment: @LexLi Installed Tracing and followed the steps, but the log files directory is empty. It doesn't throw any errors apparently.

Comment: If you enable detailed errors for your website in IIS, you will see an error page with detailed information and a 404 sub-status code,  which will indicate a more specific reason for the error 404. Open IIS >> select "Error Pages" >> select "Edit Feature Settings" >> select "Detailed Errors".

Comment: @YurongDai I am using Postman and all I get is a 404 Not found. I have enabled detailed errors.

Comment: This is definitely a server issue, because I published the code on another IIS server and it worked fine.

Comment: What is the difference between the configuration of the two servers? Is it working now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a firewall issue. The company firewall was blocking the request.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).